# How to set a dynamic checkbox as true/false

Tags: c#, dynamic, checkbox

im a bit wondered..

I have multiple checkboxes which will be generated at runtime with the name chk_WoK1, chk_WoK2, Chk_WoK3.

I thought I can set them like this:

> this.Controls["chk_WoK1"].Checked = true;

but this seems not working. 
I used this because it worked already for Label Objects.

Can anybody tell me another method to assign them?

Comment: While I  am guessing that your code does not compile saying that 'Checked' is not a property of type 'Control', but it would be good if you put the exact errors you get

Comment: @Braim Agree. Plus I think he needs to typecast that control to checkbox.

Comment: You can do this, `((CheckBox) this.Controls.Find("chk_WoK1",true)[0]).Checked = true;`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because this.Controls["chk_wok1"] is going to return a Control type. you have to cast that to a CheckBox type to be ableto access that property. It worked for labels because all controls have Text property. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1865435(v=vs.110).aspx
change from

> this.Controls["chk_WoK1"].Checked = true;

to

> ((CheckBox)this.Controls["chk_WoK1"]).Checked = true;

Comment: np, no need to Thank for answers while in StackOverflow. But you can mark the answer if it fixed your problem.